# How to use XSLT with If condition and copy of elements

Tags: if-statement, xslt

I have an XSLT with

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ABCDEFG"/>
```

I tried applying If condition like below:

```
<xsl:if test="(string(STAT)='E0001') or (string(STAT)='I0002')">
    <xsl:copy-of select="ABCDEFG"/>
</xsl:if>
```

I have multiple nodes: ABCDEFG in the XML and
System is currently not selecting any of the ABCDEFG nodes
with the above IF condition.
Please let me know how to write the If condition.
Also would like to know how to write If condition with 'NOT' instead
of multiple 'OR's

The Actual Input XML is

```
<ABCDEFG>
   <STAT>E0001</STAT>
   <PQRS>Z000002</PQRS>
</ABCDEFG>
<ABCDEFG>
   <STAT>E0002</STAT>
   <PQRS>Z000002</PQRS>
</ABCDEFG>
<ABCDEFG>
   <STAT>I0002</STAT>
   <PQRS>Z000002</PQRS>
</ABCDEFG>
```

The Output wanted after XSLT is

```
<ABCDEFG>
   <STAT>E0001</STAT>
   <PQRS>Z000002</PQRS>
</ABCDEFG>
<ABCDEFG>
   <STAT>I0002</STAT>
   <PQRS>Z000002</PQRS>
</ABCDEFG>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] ishowing an input, your instruction **in context** and the expected output.

Comment: *"how to write If condition with 'NOT' instead of multiple 'OR's"* Not sure what that means.

Comment: Please show the context of your if stement. Or in other words: in what match or for-each you are using this if.

Comment: michael.hor257k solution worked for me, used it with not equal to: <xsl:copy-of select="ABCDEFG[STAT!='E0002']"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing (!) you want to do something like:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ABCDEFG[STAT='E0001' or STAT='I0002']"/>
```

Comment: Worked for me! There was no need for an IF statement. I will add the context for reference